# p:commandButton in p:dialog does not call actionListener method

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have the following page and somehow the

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" update="data" oncomplete="edit.hide();" actionListener="#{dataBean.update}" />
```

does not call the method speficied in the actionListener. I checked all the options from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) and everything seems to be correct. Am I missing something?

`Page`

```
<h:body id="body" style="margin:50px; font-size: 80%">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:form>
        <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();"
            onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();" />

        <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Processing"
            draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" width="255">
            <p:graphicImage value="./images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </p:dialog>

        <p:commandButton value="Delete selected"
            onclick="confirmationSelected.show()" />

        <p:commandButton value="Refresh data" update="data"
            style="float:right" actionListener="#{dataBean.refresh}" />

        <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{dataBean.records}" id="data"
            paginator="true" rows="10" selection="#{dataBean.selectedRecords}"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,25,50,100">

            <f:facet name="header">Stored records</f:facet>

            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
            <p:column style="width:18px; text-align:center;">
                <p:rowToggler />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Time" style="width:80px; text-align:center;"
                sortBy="#{item.time}" filterby="#{item.time}"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.time}">
                    <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="URL" style="word-break: break-all"
                sortBy="#{item.url}" filterby="#{item.url}"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.url}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Rating" style="width:80px; text-align:center;"
                sortBy="#{item.rating}" filterby="#{item.rating}"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.rating}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Key" style="width:80px; text-align:center;"
                sortBy="#{item.key}" filterby="#{item.key}"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.key}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Actions"
                style="text-align:center; width:100px;">
                <p:commandLink value="Edit" oncomplete="edit.show()"
                    update="editPanel">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dataBean.key}"
                        value="#{item.key}" />
                </p:commandLink>
                &nbsp;
                <p:commandLink value="Delete" onclick="confirmation.show()">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dataBean.key}"
                        value="#{item.key}" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
            <p:rowExpansion>
                <p:tabView>
                    <p:tab title="Page source">
                        <div
                            style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: auto; word-break: break-all">#{item.page}</div>
                    </p:tab>

                    <p:tab title="Snippet">
                        <div
                            style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: auto; word-break: break-all">#{item.snippet}</div>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure you want to delete this item?"
            header="Delete" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation"
            modal="true">
            <p:commandButton value="OK" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                actionListener="#{dataBean.deleteOne}" update="data" />
            <p:commandLink value="Cancel" onclick="confirmation.hide()" />
        </p:confirmDialog>

        <p:confirmDialog
            message="Are you sure you want to delete all selected items?"
            header="Delete" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmationSelected"
            modal="true">
            <p:commandButton value="Delete"
                oncomplete="confirmationSelected.hide()"
                actionListener="#{dataBean.deleteSelected}" update="data" />
            <p:commandLink value="Cancel" onclick="confirmationSelected.hide()" />
        </p:confirmDialog>

    </h:form>
    <p:dialog header="Edit record" widgetVar="edit" resizable="true"
        width="850" height="500" modal="true">
        <h:form id="editPanel">
            <h:outputText value="Record ID = #{dataBean.selectedRecordKey}"
                style="font-size:12pt;" />
            <p:separator />
            <h:panelGrid columns="6">
                <h:outputText style="margin-left:-2px;" value="Time:" />
                <h:inputText value="#{dataBean.selectedRecordTime}"
                    style="width: 230px" />

                <h:outputText style="margin-left:20px;" value="Url:" />
                <h:inputText value="#{dataBean.selectedRecordUrl}"
                    style="width: 375px" />

                <h:outputText style="margin-left:20px;" value="Rating:" />
                <p:spinner value="#{dataBean.selectedRecordRating}" min="1" max="5"
                    style="width: 30px" width="20" showOn="never" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <p:tabView>
                <p:tab title="Page source">
                    <h:inputTextarea value="#{dataBean.selectedRecordPage}" rows="13" cols="108" />
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab title="Snippet">
                    <h:inputTextarea value="#{dataBean.selectedRecordSnippet}" rows="13" cols="108" />
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
            <br />
            <p:commandButton value="Save" update="data"
                oncomplete="edit.hide();" actionListener="#{dataBean.update}" />
            <p:commandLink value="Cancel" onclick="edit.hide()"
                style="margin-left:10px;" />
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</f:view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your dialog you are placing your contents inside a new Form

`<h:form id="editPanel">`

Can you remove this form and rerun your code ?

So now all your content should be inside one form which you are creating at this line :

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
<h:form>
```

Comment: Command and input components should be in form, shouldn't they?

Comment: I did that and the dialog is not updated when the `Edit` button in table is pressed - so empty dialog (without data) shows up.

Comment: my bad.. on edit you are updating this "<h:form id="editPanel">", instead of form can you place all your component inside a panel and give the panel id ="editPanel", post your findings.

Comment: I've done this before (id to `<h:panelGrid columns="6">`) - with no progress.

Comment: OK. I found the problem elsewhere - bad type in bean and no error so I didn't know. But one last problem still exists. If I save the edited values from the dialog, the data table is not updated. I have to press F5 to see the changes...

Comment: once you are done with editing the row then you will have to update the p:datatable or else it wont update itself,

Comment: And this won't do the trick? `<p:commandButton value="Save" update="data"..`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5561/discussion-between-mprabhat-and-tomas)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show declaration of your dataBean.update ?

Usually action listener method should return void and have ActionEvent as parameter.

Did you try to use action instead of actionListener?